# how to start a service in android

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I have a problem when start the service:

here is the code getting started service
I put in a onClick of a button

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(Contexts.getAppContext(), Modul_GeoTrack.MyServices.class);


    Contexts.getAppContext().startService(myIntent);
```

and here is the declaration in manifest:

```
 <service android:name=".MyServices"></service>
```

but it is still displaying this problem

> Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4
>   cmp=com.example.projet/Modul_GeoTrack.MyServices (has extras) }: not
>   found

Please someone give me a solution I'm really blocking blocking..:'(:''''(

Comment: are you starting service in non activity class??

Comment: your service ie Myservice is inside Modul_GeoTrack??? if yes then specity in that way in manefest

Comment: when written like that in manifest :   <service android:name="Modul_GeoTrack.MyServices"></service>    ;gives this warning:use '$' instid of '.' for inner class or use only lowercase letters in packages names

Comment: so use '$' as the warning suggests

Comment: A service cannot be a regular inner class. It can be a static inner class, in which case the `$` syntax is valid. This is rather unusual, though.

Comment: so how to write in manifest to resolve this problem, the service that is in the package Modul_GeoTrack

Comment: so how to write in manifest to resolve this problem, the service that is in the package Modul_GeoTrack

Comment: Try to give full path for your service like `com.example.demo.servicename` like that